# ClassNotFound in provided struts framework

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts

I'm having issues using a struts form tag, that's returning a ClassNotFoundException:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class com.myproject.form.GenerationForm: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myproject.form.GenerationForm
org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:568)
```

With the following structure:

```
tomcat
|_____lib
|_____webapps
      |______myApp
             |____WEB_INF
```

I have the struts JAR's in Tomcat's lib folder. And my class is inside the webapps WEB_INF folder.

I know that the class is correctly loaded, because with a basic JSP, I can instantiate it and use it normally. The ClassNotFoundException is being thrown only when trying to be used by struts.

In the struts config file, there's the form bean defined as (struts-config.xml):

```
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="generation"
            type="com.myproject.form.GenerationForm" />
    </form-beans>
    [...]

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/generator" type="com.myproject.action.Generator"
        input="/secure/confirm.jsp" name="generation" scope="request">
            <forward name="error" path="/page/error.page" />
            <forward name="close" path="/page/close.page" />
            <forward name="results" path="/results.action?id={0}" redirect="true" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

The form is defined as (page.jsp):

```
<html:form styleId="confirmForm" styleClass="confirm" action="/generator.action" method="POST">
     [...]
</html:form>
```

To test this issue, I've generated a JAR file containing my app's classes in tomcat's lib folder and, in that case, the Struts framework can load the class and everything works as expected.

Since the classes should be loaded by the app's classloader, why can't Struts "see" my webapp classes ? Is there a way to specify where should they be loaded from ?

Comment: I'm no expert but I would say that the classloader would need the classpath of your GenerationForm class with is project specific (And you should not).  Best option would be to put struts libs in your project folder.  And project-wise, most of the time EAR/WAR file should be independent from server (IMO).

Comment: Shouldn't the class loader of tomcat's lib JAR's in the context of a specific Webapp, also contain the classes from that Webapp WEB-INF's folder ? For example, you can instantiate Spring beans with your project classes and have the Spring jars in the webserver's lib ?

Comment: Think Tomcat loads is libs prior to you application and does not add the classpath.  Have you tried the shared folder instead for your struts lib? Might do the trick.

Comment: Struts 1 jars specifically should *not* be in Tomcat's lib directory.